# column formatting for multiline bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I am trying to print a nice and pretty table displaying values of few(3) variables.  One of the variable contains multiple line as its content.  Which is distorting the format of the table generated.

Tried with `echo -e` first which didn't helped to tried leveraging `printf` but still not able to correct the formatting. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
var1=10
var2=20
var3=$(cat temp.db) #This is causing issue.

printf "%-10s%-10s%-30s\n" "var1" "var2" "var3"
printf "%-10s%-10s%-30s\n" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

where temp.db is structured as follow:

```
cat temp.db

2 user1
3 user2
5 user3
6 user7
9 user9
```

## Desired output:

```
var1      var2    var3
 10       20      2 user1
                  3 user2
                  5 user3
                  6 user7
                  9 user9
```

## What I am currently getting:

```
var1      var2      var3
10        20        2 user1
3 user2
5 user3
6 user7
9 user9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `awk`-man <sup>(a)</sup>. The following transcript shows it in action:

```
yup> awk '
...>    BEGIN {
...>        v1 = 10; v2 = 20; f="%-10s %-10s %-30s\n";
...>        printf f, "var1", "var2", "var3";
...>    }
...>    {
...>        printf f, v1, v2, $0;
...>        v1 = ""; v2 = "";
...>    }' inputFile

var1       var2       var3
10         20         2 user1
                      3 user2
                      5 user3
                      6 user7
                      9 user9
```

Ignore the `...>` things, they're my continuation prompt `PS2` so I can nicely line up multi-line statements (some of the `;` characters are also superfluous but I do that just for consistency).

The code simply sets up the format string and initial values for `var1/2`, then prints the header in the `BEGIN` block. Then, for each input line, it outputs your desired columns, formatted as needed.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Think Superman but with less of a square jaw, geekier glasses and probably a pocket protector as well :-)